# Python and psycopg2 - raw sql select from table with integer criteria

Tags: python

It should be simple, bit I've spent the last hour searching for the answer. This is using psycopg2 on python 2.6.

I need something like this:

```
    special_id = 5
    sql = """
          select count(*) as ct,
            from some_table tbl
           where tbl.id = %(the_id)
      """
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, {"the_id" : special_id})
```

I cannot get this to work. Were `special_id` a string, I could replace `%(the_id)` with `%(the_id)s` and things work well. However, I want it to use the integer so that it hits my indexes correctly.

There is a surprising lack of specific information on psycopg2 on the internet. I hope someone has an answer to this seemingly simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), since in psycopg2 `paramstyle` is `pyformat`, you need to use `%(the_id)s` even for non-strings -- trust it to do the right thing.

BTW, internet searches will work better if you use the correct spelling (no `h` there), but even if you mis-spelled, I'm surprised you didn't get a "did you mean" hint (I did when I deliberately tried!).

Comment: I *hate* trusting DB drivers to do the right thing. I've been bitten by implicit Sybase date conversion missing indexes on too many times.  I guess I have no choice with psycopg. As for the spelling, I guess the mind-image of the correct spelling of psycho over ruled any Google suggestions - thanks for the pointer.